# doIf not working with session

Tags: scala, gatling

I´m trying to use Gatling, where I just want to execute some steps in the first scenario iteration, here my code

```
def create(): ScenarioBuilder = {
    scenario(name)
      .exec(session => session.set("DEBUG", debug_set))
      .exec(session => session.set("client_id", session.userId))
      .doIf(session => session("initialized").asOption[String].isEmpty) {
        exec(Identity.getIdentityToken)
        exec(session => session.set("initialized", "true"))
      }
      .exitHereIfFailed
      .during(Duration(15, MINUTES)) {
        exec(X.setupVars)
          .exec(X.create)
          .pause(Duration(1, SECONDS))
          .exec(X.get)
      }
  }
}
```

Somehow first iteration where initialized it´s not defined it´s not getting there, since I dont see the logs the execution of the one of the steps.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One dot is missing for the second `exec` in your `doIf`:

```
.doIf(session => session("initialized").asOption[String].isEmpty) {
    exec(Identity.getIdentityToken)
    .exec(session => session.set("initialized", "true"))
}
```

Cheers,
Paul as well :)
Gatling Team

Comment: Thank a lot!, although Gatling could complain about the missed dots instead just run and not executed the block

Comment: There's almost no way for Gatling to check this. What you're doing is discarding the value returned by a method call. AFAIK, even the Java compiler doesn't check this, only static analysis tools such as SonarQube will issue some warnings.

Comment: Any idea why now it´s executed for every scenario?, I guess because the scope of the scenario is per user/scenario. Any idea how to share those session values between user/scenario? I have 100 user per this scenario and I dont want initialize 100 times.